# Given ID, find entries that have dueAt less than ID.dueAt

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a single query. I have a collection of `Event`. Each event has a `dueAt` field which is a number. Given id of an event, i want to find all events that have a dueAt less than the dueAt of the event at given id.

Here is example of what I mean, my collections has this pseudocode:

```
id: 1,
dueAt: 100

id: 2,
dueAt: 101

id: 3,
dueAt: 102
```

Then I only have id of "3" I want do a query like:

```
eventCollection.find({
    { dueAt: { '<': 'dueAtOfId(3)' }}
});
```

Is there a name for this technique? Anyone know what they call it in MySQL?

I can do this easily in two queries, but i want to avoid that for learning, pseudocode:

```
const events = await eventCollection.find({ _id: 3 });
const maxDueAt = events[0].dueAt;
const result = await eventCollection.find({ dueAt: { '<': maxDueAt } });
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking *`Then I only have id of "3" I want do a query like:`?*

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks for asking, I don't want to do a query on id 3, to get the dueAt, then do a 2nd query with that dueAt, I'll edit it in now.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I added in the snippet of doing two queries, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the below single query

```
const result = await eventCollection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": 3 }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "eventCollection",
    "let": { "dueAt": "$dueAt" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gte": ["$dueAt", "$$dueAt"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "result"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$result" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$result" }}
])
```

Comment: Wow so brilliant, thank you!!! Is there a name for this technique? We can do it in SQL too right? Is this single query performance better than that of two queries?

Comment: This is an [aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). *We can do it in SQL too right* We can say it as left join with mysql. *Is this single query performance better than that of two queries?* depends on requirement

Comment: Thank you @Anthony!